Why do we have $b_n\cdot 1=0$ in Heisenberg vertex algebra for the annihilation operator $b_n$?
I am reading "Vertex Algebras and Algebraic Curves Second Edition" by Edward Frenkel and David Ben-Zvi. In section 2.1.2, they define the Heisenberg Lie algebra $\mathcal{H}$ as the central extension $0\to \mathbb{C}\textbf{1}\to \mathcal{H}' \to\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]\to 0$. It has the basis $b_n=t^n$ which satisfy the relations $[b_n,b_m]=n\delta_{n,-m}\textbf{1}$ and $[\textbf{1},b_n]=0$. Then, define its Fock representation by $\pi=\tilde{\mathcal{H}}\otimes_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+}\mathbb{C}$ where $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ is the Weyl algebra that is the quotient by the two sided ideal $(\textbf{1}-1)$ of the completion $\tilde{U}(\mathcal{H})$ of the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathcal{H}')$ of $\mathcal{H}'$, and $\mathbb{C}$ is the representation of $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+$. By PBW theorem, we have $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}\cong \tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+\otimes \tilde{\mathcal{H}}_-$. Therefore, we can have the isomorphism $\pi\cong \tilde{H}_-$.
My understanding is that
\begin{aligned}
\pi &=\tilde{\mathcal{H}}\otimes_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+}\mathbb{C}&\\
&\cong (\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_-\otimes \tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+) \otimes_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+}\mathbb{C}&\\
&\cong \tilde{\mathcal{H}}_-\otimes (\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+ \otimes_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+}\mathbb{C})&\\
&\cong \tilde{\mathcal{H}}_-\otimes \mathbb{C}& (\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+ \otimes_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+}\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}~~ \text{since the elements of $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+$ are automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$})\\
&\cong \tilde{\mathcal{H}}_-& (\text{Consider $\mathbb{C}$ as the coefficents})
\end{aligned}
Is this correct?
Then, the book says that $b_n\cdot 1=0$ for $n\geq 0$ from the definition. I attach this part from the book here.

Where is this rule $b_n\cdot 1=0$ for $n\geq 0$ from? It is the consequence of which definition? What I can find from other materials all define the vacuum vector $|0\rangle$ with this property directly, but this book says that $1$ has this property due to another definition than define it as the vacuum vector $|0\rangle =1$. But I cannot derive this rule from other defintion given in this section.

The answer is one line but maybe I will also describe how $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}
$ acts on $\pi$, we have  $$\pi =\tilde{\mathcal{H}}\otimes_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+}\mathbb{C}$$ which we take $\mathbb{C}$ to be a trivial $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+$-representation ($b_n \cdot \lambda=0$ for all $n \geq 0, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$). It is important to note that $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}_+$ acts on $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ on the right and $\mathbb{C}$ on the left. Then given an abitary element in $x \otimes \lambda \in \pi$, we have:
For $b_j$ with $j <0$,  $$b_j \cdot (x \otimes \lambda)=b_j x \otimes \lambda$$
For $b_j$ with $j \geq0$,
$$b_j \cdot (x \otimes \lambda)=b_j\cdot x \otimes \lambda \tag{$*$}$$
But recall that on $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$, we have the relation
$$ b_nb_m-b_mb_n=n \delta_{n,-m} \mathbf{1} $$
Coming back to ($*$), terms with $b_n$, $n \neq j$ in $x$ (which is spanned by monomials $b_{i_1}b_{i_2}\dots b_{i_k}$) gives us
$$ b_j\cdot b_n \otimes \lambda = b_n\cdot b_j \otimes \lambda =b_n \otimes b_j \cdot\lambda = b_n \otimes 0 =0$$
The only non-zero term gives
$$ b_j\cdot b_-j \otimes \lambda = b_-j\cdot b_j +j \mathbf{1} \otimes \lambda =j \mathbf{1} \otimes \lambda$$
All and all this gives the action of $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}
$ on $\pi$:
$$
b_j \mapsto
\begin{cases} 
b_j & \text{for } j<0 & \text{(left multiplication)}\\
j \frac{\partial}{\partial b_{-j}} & \text{for } j\geq0
\end{cases}
$$
So to answer your original question, if we define the element $1 \equiv 1 \otimes \lambda \in \pi$, then $$b_n \cdot (1 \otimes \lambda )=1 \otimes b_n \cdot \lambda = 0$$

Does it mean the zero $0=b_n\otimes 0$ is not unique if we choose different $b_n$?

@user117521 not sure if I understand your question, $b_n \otimes 0$ is always $0$ regardless of the choice of $b_n$
